# How to inject two components in the same activity?

Tags: android, dagger-2

Suppose, We have two components -

1. PresentationComponent
2. XYZComponent

Now, both `PresentationComponent` and `XYZComponent` have methods `inject(MainActivity mainActivity)` in them. However, their respective modules provide different values. Example, PresentationComponent's PresentationModule @Provides context and XYZComponent's XYZModule @Provides presenter.

Here is my MainActivity code -

```
@Inject
Presenter presenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getPresentationComponent().inject(this);

    DaggerXYZComponent.builder()
            .XYZModule(new XYZModule(this))
            .build().inject(this);
}
```

However, the build will fail with an error because `PresentationComponent` will fail to provide the `Presenter` which MainActivity is expecting. How do I solve this without combining the two components into one?

The error will be on similar lines as

> .....Provider cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Comment: Don't have two Components for this. Your components represent a node of a given scope hierarchy. Clearly there shouldn't be two overlapping scopes for the same thing. In fact, Dagger disallows inheritance from multiple scopes. You probably wanted PresentationModule and XYZModule bound to a single AppComponent or ActivitySubcomponent.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That makes sense. But in my case PresentationComponent is aimed to be generic wrt what it provides (context, activity). While, I was hoping to make XYZComponent to be specific to MainAcitvity; very similar to how it is in this tutorial - https://android.jlelse.eu/android-mvp-architecture-with-dependency-injection-dee43fe47af0

Comment: You are looking for a PresentationModule, not component.